# Should I close Entity Framework dbcontext connection after raw query?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using entity framework database raw query.

```
 using var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
 command.CommandText = "select * from my_school";

 using var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
 var dataRow = ReadSchools(dataReader);

 command.Connection.Close();????
```

After `dataReader` read the result, should I close the connection or does using statement close the connection after scope? If I don't close, does the connection pool fill?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` for `DBConnection`  as following:

```
using (var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
{
 var command = conn.CreateCommand();
 command.CommandText = "select * from my_school";

 var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
 var dataRow = ReadSchools(dataReader);

 }
```

For more detail please check [Working with DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)